# Recover source code from BDB SVN Repository

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

I'm trying to recover the source code from an SVN backup which I no longer have the remote repository. This is an old project and it was using BDB as database which is no longer supported by SVN clients.

The files in this backup are:

```
db/
hooks/
locks/
format
README.txt
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Using the recover command from `svnadmin`
2. Creating a new repository using svn 1.8 (which still supports creating BDB repositories) and copying the `db/` folder. The structure of the `db/` folder is essentially different from newer versions, the one in my backup has revisions and transactions as folder, not files.
3. Downloading the source code from svn 1.6 (from [apache archives](http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/)) and compiling from scratch. I was not able to compile due to many outdated dependencies.

Some additional information:

- I'm using Linux to do this but I've also tried in Windows and Mac
- The current svn version I have installed is 1.8
- I don't have access to the original server all I have a backup zip file
- This is the content of the db folder:

```
revprops/
revs/
transactions/
txn-protorevs/
__db.001
__db.002
__db.003
DB_CONFIG
__db.register
log.0000000001
nodes
txn-current
txn-current-lock
uuid
write-lock
```

I'm stuck at this and I have no idea what else I could try to extract the source code from this repository.

Answer (score 3):

1. [This manual](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/faq/BDBtoFSFS.html) of migration may help
2. As I read (now) in [Apache Subversion 1.8 Release Notes](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#bdb-deprecated)

> The Subversion developers have decided to deprecate the repository
>   back-end based on Berkeley DB. … What this *does not* mean:  Users do
>   not have to immediately migrate their repositories to FSFS. The BDB
>   back-end will continue to work, and will receive as much test coverage
>   as it has until now.

I.e. you can, as suggested in Collab docs, have repository with BDB-backend and perform all usual administrative operations with it - create dump and load it into new repo with FSFS-backend. If your db isn't broken after `recover` then dump|load trick have to get the expected result

Comment: Both `recover` and `dump` yield the same error:
`svnadmin: E000002: Can't open file 'db/DB_CONFIG': No such file or directory`

Comment: Hey Frederico, Did you get it resolved? I have the same error while recovering repo.

Comment: I am trying  `svnadmin dump my_repo` and get
`svnadmin: E160033: Failed to load module for FS type 'bdb'`